# How to click elements with no ID

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have the following HTML and I am trying to click the element named tasks.

```
*<td class="class_popup2_menuitem_caption" unselectable="on" nowrap="">Tasks</td>*
```

I have tried this:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/table/tbody//td[contains(text(), 'Tasks')]") 
x.click()
```

However, I get the following response.

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score -2):

***I am trying to showcase the root cause of this exception using selenium & java. Please try to implement in python.***

**ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable** is caused when an element is found, but you can not interact with it. For instance, you may not be able to click or send keys.

***There could be several reasons for this:***

```
 - The element is not visible / not displayed The element is off screen
 - The element is behind another element or hidden Some other action
 - needs to be performed by the user first to enable it.
```

Strategies that may work to make it interactable (depending on the circumstance.)

***1. Wait until an element is visible / clickable***

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

***2. Scroll until the element is within the the display***

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element);
```

***3. Use javascript to interact directly with the DOM***

```
JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
javascript.executeScript("var element = document.querySelector('locator'); element.value = 'whatever';")
```

***4. Perform whatever other action is necessary and possibly wait until after that.***

Comment: I understand you are trying to help but posting an answer in another language than what OP requested is [against the rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290046/if-the-question-is-specifically-about-a-certain-language-is-an-answer-in-anothe).